# Error on Ado destination ( Null password given logon denied)

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I have saved in dts.Config Connection strings of .Net Providers\OracleClient Data Provider, connection manager, but if I run Dts package I get an error:

> Null password given logon denied

Can anyone give some idea please, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you've got your connection string wrong in your config file.

Here's a great resource for connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Compare yours against the ones listed there. I bet you're supplying a `User Id` but no `Password` (standard security).